# Laravel 7 - Scoping problem in Nested Resource Route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

### Routes:

I have a nested resource route definition like this:

```
Route::resource('posts.comments', 'CommentController');
```

That produces the following routes:

```
+--------+-----------+--------------------------------------+------------------------+------------------------------------------------+------------+
| Domain | Method    | URI                                  | Name                   | Action                                         | Middleware |
+--------+-----------+--------------------------------------+------------------------+------------------------------------------------+------------+
|        | GET|HEAD  | posts/{post}/comments                | posts.comments.index   | App\Http\Controllers\CommentController@index   | web        |
|        | POST      | posts/{post}/comments                | posts.comments.store   | App\Http\Controllers\CommentController@store   | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | posts/{post}/comments/create         | posts.comments.create  | App\Http\Controllers\CommentController@create  | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | posts/{post}/comments/{comment}      | posts.comments.show    | App\Http\Controllers\CommentController@show    | web        |
|        | PUT|PATCH | posts/{post}/comments/{comment}      | posts.comments.update  | App\Http\Controllers\CommentController@update  | web        |
|        | DELETE    | posts/{post}/comments/{comment}      | posts.comments.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\CommentController@destroy | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | posts/{post}/comments/{comment}/edit | posts.comments.edit    | App\Http\Controllers\CommentController@edit    | web        |
+--------+-----------+--------------------------------------+------------------------+------------------------------------------------+------------+
```

---

### Relationships (In Models):

`Post` model:

```
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
}
```

`Comment` model:

```
public function post()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Post::class);
}
```

---

### Dummy Data (In Tables):

`posts` table:

```
+----+--------+-----------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | title  | body                        | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+--------+-----------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 1  | Post 1 | This is the body of Post 1. | 2020-07-29 11:20:53 | 2020-07-29 11:20:53 |
| 2  | Post 2 | This is the body of Post 2. | 2020-07-29 11:21:13 | 2020-07-29 11:21:13 |
+----+--------+-----------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

`comments` table:

```
+----+---------+-----------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | post_id | body                        | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+---------+-----------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 1  | 1       | The comment for the Post 1. | 2020-07-29 11:22:27 | 2020-07-29 11:22:27 |
| 2  | 2       | The comment for the Post 2. | 2020-07-29 11:22:32 | 2020-07-29 11:22:32 |
+----+---------+-----------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

---

In the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#implicit-binding):

> When using a custom keyed implicit binding as a nested route
> parameter, Laravel will automatically scope the query to retrieve the
> nested model by its parent using conventions to guess the relationship
> name on the parent.

So, `{comment}` is supposed to be child of `{post}`. But when I hit `/posts/1/comments/2`, it retrieves **comment** with an id of **2** which belongs to the **post** with an id of **2**. The expected result would be `NotFoundHttpException`.

It works fine when I define the routes individually like this:

```
Route::get('/posts/{post}/comments/{comment:id}', 'CommentController@show');
```

Why is this happening?

Also tried to customize the default key name in both `Post` and `Comment` models:

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'id';
}
```

But no luck.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: seems it is something that only comes into play when using a custom keyed implicit binding ... if you would like you could extend the ResourceRegistrar to add this information to the routes it defines if you really wanted to

Comment: `use App\Post;
use App\Comment;

Route::get('posts/{post}/comments/{comment:id}', function (Post $post, Comment $comment) {
    return $comment;
});` Try that if you get data you have problem on `CommentController@show`

Comment: @xNoJustice It works this way which I already tried. But I have a nested resource route definition.

Comment: Add one control to `CommentController@show` for fix your problem.`$comment = Comment::where('post_id',$post)->where('id', $comment)->get();` this control causes an error to return when the wrong post is selected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did some digging and reached a conclusion after reading `Illuminate\Routing\PendingResourceRegistration.php` class from the [source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/src/Illuminate/Routing/PendingResourceRegistration.php#L123). **I have to use custom keyed implicit binding to make it work as I expect.**

`Route::resource()` method takes (optional) third argument which is an associative array. So, I need to override the route parameter name via `parameters` key using this argument.

```
Route::resource('posts.comments', 'CommentController', [
    'parameters' => ['comments' => 'comment:id'],
]);
```

or

```
Route::resource('posts.comments', 'CommentController')->parameters([
    'comments' => 'comment:id',
]);
```

It works either way.

Answer (score 1):

## Laravel 8 and 9

To achieve your goal you can use laravel scope resource route feature. For example:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\PhotoCommentController;
 
Route::resource('photos.comments', PhotoCommentController::class)->scoped([
    'comment' => 'slug',
]);
```

Change slug to id if you do not want to use the custom key. See the doc [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#restful-scoping-resource-routes).
You can also try the following:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\PhotoCommentController;
 
Route::resource('photos.comments', PhotoCommentController::class)->scoped();
```

You can find the source for scoped method [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9.x/src/Illuminate/Routing/PendingResourceRegistration.php#L223).